# Cron expression to run job every 3hrs and 15 mins

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-batch, cronexpression

I need a particular job to be run every 3hrs and 15 mins .

Will this expression serve my purpose ?

> batch.backupscores.cronExpression=0 0/15 0/3 * * ?

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

No, this expression won't work and I believe you can't express this using Cron. But you can use [simple trigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05) instead.

Running job **every 195** minutes will work (3 * 60 minutes + 15).

Answer (score 0):

0 15 0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21 * * ?

this will serve the purpose